# How to reuse parent values in xslt transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a deeply nested xml file, and want transform it to flat csv. Therefore I have to go to the deepest path (here: `availability`), and reuse values from parents (here: `category`, `element`).

Example:

```
<market>
    <category>
        <type>kids</type>
    </category>
    <items>
        <element>
            <name>police car</name>
            <type>toy</type>
            <color>blue</color>
            <availability>
                <stock cat="A" in="5"/>
                <stock cat="B" in="2"/>
            </availability>
        </element>
        </element>
            ...
        </element>
    </items>
</market>
```

Desired csv output:

```
kids,police car, toy, blue, A, 5
kids,police car, toy, blue, B, 2
```

Note how the `kids` value is copied to each resulting `element` line, and how each `element` is copied to each `availability` view.

I stared as follows, but of course this does not give the desired result. Because I don't know how to:

- iterate nested child elements properly
- concatenate the values as csv, resuing parent-found values

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>     <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
>     <xsl:template match="market">
>         <xsl:for-each select="//category">
>             <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
>         </xsl:for-each>
>
>         <xsl:for-each select="//items//element">
>             <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
>             <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
>             <xsl:value-of select="color"/>
>         </xsl:for-each>
>
>         <xsl:for-each select="//items//element//availability//stock">
>             <xsl:value-of select="//@cat"/>
>             <xsl:value-of select="//@in"/>
>         </xsl:for-each>
>     </xsl:template>
> ```

The following might work, but I don't know if that's the way to go:

```
<xsl:template match="market">
    <xsl:variable name="ctype">
        <xsl:value-of select="market/category/type"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="//items//element">
    <xsl:variable name="elem">
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="copy-of(.)!(.//name, .//type, .//color)" separator=";"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- nesting for-each -->
    <xsl:for-each select="availability//stock">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$elem"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="copy-of(.)!(.//@cat, .//@in)" separator=";"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually write a template matching those elements that map to a line and select the other values as needed through XPath navigation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//availability/stock"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="stock">
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::market/category/type, ancestor::element!(name, type, color), @cat, @in" separator=", "/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That allows for a compact and clear notation of which values compose a line in the CSV file.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM9

A static header information like the `category/type` could also be stored in a global variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="category-type" select="market/category/type"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//availability/stock"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="stock">
      <xsl:value-of select="$category-type, ancestor::element!(name, type, color), @cat, @in" separator=", "/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM9/1

A third way in XSLT 3 is to capture values in a declarative way using accumulators:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="cat-type" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="market/category/type" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="element-name" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="item/element" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/element/name" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="element-type" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="item/element" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/element/type" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="element-color" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="item/element" select="()"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/element/color" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//availability/stock"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="stock">
      <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('cat-type'), accumulator-before('element-name'), accumulator-before('element-type'), accumulator-before('element-color'), @cat, @in" separator=", "/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM9/2

That has the advantage that you could adapt it to streaming with some changes to that you could transform huge inputs with Saxon 9.8 EE without storing the complete XML input tree in memory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all" />

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="cat-type" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="market/category/type/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="element-name" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="item/element" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/element/name/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="element-type" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="item/element" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/element/type/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="element-color" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="item/element" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/element/color/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="outermost(//availability/stock)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stock">
        <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('cat-type'), accumulator-before('element-name'), accumulator-before('element-type'), accumulator-before('element-color'), @cat, @in" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="market">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//stock">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::market/category/type
            |ancestor::market/items/element/name
            |ancestor::market/items/element/type
            |ancestor::market/items/element/color
            |@cat
            |@in" separator=", "/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
kids, police car, toy, blue, A, 5
kids, police car, toy, blue, B, 2
```

Comment: Is this better than nesting multiple `for-each` loops (which might also work when using `xsl:variable` inside)
?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit sing `<xsl:variable />` and nested loops for it.