# Transform multi-element XML to CSV with XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to understand how XSLT can iterate over multiple elements and output data from the those elements and their older and younger siblings.  See the example below:

```
<a>
    <b name="first">
        <c value="C Value">C Text</c>
        <d>D1 Text</d>
        <d>D2 Text</d>
        <e>E Text</e>
    </b>
    <b name="second">
        <c value="C Value">C Text</c>
        <d>D1 Text</d>
        <d>D2 Text</d>
        <d>D3 Text</d>
        <e>E Text</e>
    </b>
    <b name="third">
        <c value="C Value">C Text</c>
        <e>E Text</e>
    </b>
</a>
```

I would like the output to be like the following (assuming for simplicity that each element's text will not contain commas).

```
first,C Value,C Text,D1 Text,E Text
first,C Value,C Text,D2 Text,E Text
second,C Value,C Text,D1 Text,E Text
second,C Value,C Text,D2 Text,E Text
second,C Value,C Text,D3 Text,E Text
third,C Value,C Text,,E Text
```

So there could be an arbitrary number of `<d>` elements (or none at all).  Each CSV line must contain the information from `<c>` (the older sibling of `<d>`), the information from one instance of `<d>`, and the information from `<e>`, the younger sibling of `<d>`. (I may be making up this notion of younger and older, but it seems to make sense.)

I haven't worked with XSLT before, so I really don't know where to start with it.  The examples I've found for iterating over elements do not make it clear how I can pull values from later in the document (e.g. `<e>` in the example) and return to another instance of the element (e.g. `<d>`).  I've written an implementation of this in Python with lxml, but would like to see if XSLT is better suited for this transformation.

**EDIT:**
I just saw that an answer was posted which I will be studying in detail to try to understand it.  But just to share what I've been working on, here is the XSL that I have been developing.  It fails to output anything when there is no `<d>` value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="a">       
        <xsl:for-each select="b">
            <xsl:call-template name="match-b"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="match-b" match="b">
        <xsl:for-each select="d">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../c/@value"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../c"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../e"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**:

```
first,C value,C Text,D1 Text,E Text
first,C value,C Text,D2 Text,E Text
second,C value,C Text,D1 Text,E Text
second,C value,C Text,D2 Text,E Text
second,C value,C Text,D3 Text,E Text
```

Comment: The expression language used within XSLT is XPath so start with a tutorial on XPath, then you know the terminology and how to navigate from one node to another. For an example of XML to CSV see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369518/how-to-reuse-parent-values-in-xslt-transformation/50373792#50373792 for instance. Your problem, however, has the difficulty that you seem to want to create data from non-existent `d` elements, that would require an intermediary step that create a `d` within those `b[not(d)]` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate to preceding or following sibling or the parent node using XPath. To output a line with XSLT 2 or later you can use `xsl:value-of select="expression-to-compute-column-values" separator=","`, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:mode name="add-dummy-d" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="normalized-input">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-dummy-d"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="b[not(d)]/c" mode="add-dummy-d">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <d/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$normalized-input/a/b/d"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d">
      <xsl:value-of select="../@name, preceding-sibling::c/(@value, .), ., following-sibling::e" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As said in a comment, an intermediary step adding an empty `d` for those `b` that don't have is needed or at least one way to ensure you get the last row of your sample output.

Online sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaF7.